# Passing a list of conditions to AND

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, regions, boolean-computation

Say I have a list of some conditions, such as

```
list = {y<x,x<0}
```

And I'd like to plug this into `RegionPlot`, such as

```
RegionPlot[y<x && x<0, {x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1}]
```

but I can't figure out how to do so. I'm not sure why `And[list]` doesn't produce the desired result, this seems like this should be the default behavior for `And`, unless there's a way to do this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Try `And @@ {y < x, x < 0}` (and look up `Apply`).

Comment: Oh thanks so much, that makes perfect sense now, I had wondered what `@@` did.

Comment: You're welcome.